# byte array vs spring resources: What are the differences and pros and cons of the two?

Tags: arrays, spring, image, file, resources

```java
    @GetMapping("/images/{fileId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> find(@PathVariable Long fileId) {
        ...
    }

    @GetMapping("/images/{fileId}")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> find(@PathVariable Long fileId) {
        ...
    }
```

What are the differences and pros and cons between returning a byte array to display an image and returning a spring resource class?

I searched for related topics but couldn't find any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Reosurce` interface and in this case it can be `ByteArrayResource` implementation provides several methods for processing the internal byte array such as `getContentAsByteArray()` which returns the content as just an array of bytes, `getContentAsString(Charset charset)` which returns the content as a string using the passed encoding, `getInputStream()` which returns a wrapper for further processing the content which is a byte array and some other methods which you can read in the documentation.
[ByteArrayResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ByteArrayResource.html)
[Resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html)

In fact, the main advantage of using this abstraction is precisely in the additional methods that allow the client to perform byte array transformations without knowing how these transformations are performed, as well as obtain information about the source of the content (byte array) and more